# getting Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: gzuncompress() in ddev typo3

Tags: php, typo3

hi i am getting the following error in typo3.

```
Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: gzuncompress(): need dictionary in /var/www/html/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/Backend/Typo3DatabaseBackend.php line 157
```

does someone has a solution for this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'DB' => [
    'Connections' => [
        'Default' => [
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'driver' => 'mysqli',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Use charset utf8mb4 in your LocalConiguration.php